Generating PDF from Quote - No output via Flow
We utilize a third-party program to generate Quote PDFs - "Quote Editor". It uses VF pages as templates to do so. This works quite well using its native functionality (but this requires users to press a button on the Quote page to generate the PDF).
Edit: I can confirm the VF Page is correctly able to generate a PDF from the Quote object using the page's URL or via a "Create PDF" button on the record.
I've created a new Apex class that should do the following:

Generate the PDF from the Quote using the VF Page we currently use with 'Quote Editor'
Save the PDF directly to the Quote object (ideally under the "Quote PDFs" related records)

I've been troubleshooting this on/off for a few days now, referencing many of the available threads about this. Note: This is one of my first attempts at customizing Apex code - please forgive any significant oversights.
The current issue I'm stuck on occurs after the action is triggered by the flow. The Apex action does not fail, but simply returns "Outputs: None". Here is that debug information from the flow:
Generate PDF
Inputs:
quoteIds = {!NewQuote.Id} (0Q0VB000000B0az0AC)
Outputs:
None.

I feel like the Apex is potentially not seeing the generated PDF before the save action is completed. Does anyone have any insight into how I might be able to address this?
Here is the current version of my Apex Class:
    public class QuoteEditorPDFGenerator {

    @InvocableMethod(label='Generate Quote Editor PDF')
    
    public static void generateQuotePDF(List<Id> quoteIds) {
        for (Id quoteId : quoteIds) {
        
            // Generate the PDF from the VF page
            PageReference pdfPage = Page.qe__QuotePDF;
            pdfPage.getParameters().put('id', quoteId);
            
            Blob pdfBlob;
            pdfBlob = pdfPage.getContentAsPDF();
            
            // Step 1: Create a ContentVersion record with the actual PDF data
            ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
            cv.Title = 'Quote_' + quoteId; // This sets the file name
            cv.PathOnClient = 'Quote_' + quoteId + '.pdf';
            cv.VersionData = pdfBlob;
            cv.IsMajorVersion = true;
            insert cv;

            // Step 2: Query the ContentDocumentId safely
            ContentDocument cd;
            try {
                cd = [SELECT Id FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id = :cv.ContentDocumentId LIMIT 1];
            } catch (QueryException e) {
                System.debug('No ContentDocument found for ContentVersion with Id: ' + cv.Id);
                continue; // Skip this iteration if no ContentDocument is found
            }

            // Step 3: Link the ContentDocument to the Quote
            if (cd != null) {
                ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink();
                cdl.ContentDocumentId = cd.Id;
                cdl.LinkedEntityId = quoteId; // Link it to the Quote record
                cdl.ShareType = 'V'; // Viewer permissions
                cdl.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
                insert cdl;
            }
        }
    }
}


Your flow is after save, right?

@DavidCheng This Apex Action takes place in the same flow that the Quote record is created. Is that potentially why this is returning no result? It can't see the created Quote ID until after the Flow completes/saves?
Would running a sub-flow (or just another record-triggered flow) to trigger the PDF creation be a potential solution?

No I meant is the flow a Before Save flow or an After Save flow?

@DavidCheng Understood - this is actually a screen flow. I'm assuming that would be considered an After Save flow?

I'm going to assume there's an issue with the flow seeing the "saved" Quote record. I'll try to figure out how to avoid this, maybe with another flow.
